# Circulate, but in CSS3

Tags: css, animation

I'm trying to use CSS3 to create a similar circulating example like the flying unicorn in the below link:

http://css-tricks.com/examples/Circulate/

The unicorn example utilizes jQuery, which is fun and all but I was hoping to pull it off with either animation, transform or translate or something else. So far all I can do is have my div swing around like a propeller. I've searched all around for an answer and tried a number of things on my own but nothing has worked.

Help!

Comment: Really my question can be summed up more simply. I feel stupid asking this but does anyone know how I take a circular transform keyframe (so 0deg to 360deg) and create a more elliptical transform? I'm at a loss...

Comment: You really should provide what you tried next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using 3d transforms.

A solution for Chrome:

```
.container {
    -webkit-perspective: 600px;
    -webkit-perspective-origin-x: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 300px;
    top: 85px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(10px);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.test {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
     -webkit-animation: orbit 4s infinite linear; 
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -89deg) translateX(300px);
    z-index: -1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes orbit {
    0% {-webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 0deg) translateX(200px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 0deg);}
  100% {-webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 360deg) translateX(200px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -360deg);}
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QMDLy/)

You will have problems porting the full demo to IE (the part about the circle hiding behind the rectangle)

Comment: It can also be done without the need for a `translate` by using a negative `transform-origin` as well

Comment: But then, how do you counter-rotate ?

Comment: By using a pseudo-element or another element. Not a perfect solution, but it is cleaner and more reusable when you want multiple elements to do the same thing with different path lengths. I suppose I should have commented on the question, not your answer with this

Comment: It was a rhetoric question ... Well, yes, in some ways is cleaner. I think it is a matter of tastes. I usually don't like adding wrappers in the DOM, and find pseudo elements harder to understand. But i Do agree that if you want to have multiple objects, your proposal is cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution

**[Working Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/surjithctly/pen/oyGsI)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS3**

```
.circle {
  background:grey;
  border-radius:100%;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:0;
  animation: rotate 10s linear infinite;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(150px) rotate(-45deg);
}

@keyframes rotate {
    from { transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(150px) rotate(0deg); }
    to   { transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(150px) rotate(-360deg); }
}
```

May be you can find better solution, This is my way of doing it. Hope it help you to understand better.